# GDAL_Translate - ERROR 6: Too many command options - Batch Processing

Tags: qgis, batch, gdal-translate

I am trying to batch convert a set of JPEGs into ASCII text files.  Below is the code I am running (I added the "..." for privacy, it does not actually appear in the code).

`gdal_translate -b 1 -of AAIGrid "C:/Users/.../Cropped Pixel Profile Images/*.jpg" "C:/Users/.../Cropped Pixel Profile Images/ASCII Converted Files/*.txt"`

The message I am getting back is `ERROR 6: Too many command options 'C:/Users/.../Cropped Pixel Profile Images/-10EV.jpg'`.

I would just do this whole process through the "translate batch mode" GUI in QGIS, except that I need to add `-b 1` to the code, which can't be done for batch processed items (maybe that's a potential bug/ feature request for future versions of Q).

I am also looking for a way to execute this within QGIS, so that I can run the same command on both OSX and Windows. (If it is platform specific, what is the same command for terminal in OSX).

Anybody have any idea why I am running into this error?

Comment: I don't work on Windows, but this looks like the wildcard is being expanded and you are supplying too many files. I doubt `gdal_translate` has built in support for batch processing. Maybe a simple for loop could be used?

Comment: `for %i in (*.jpg) do gdal_translate  -b 1 -of AAIGrid %i %i.txt`

Comment: What would above command be for OSX, or if executed from within QGIS?